# Returning multiple values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, object

Often I am writing a function that returns multiple values, such as a pair of coordinates:

```
function get_coords() {
  return ???;
}
```

If I was using a language like Python, I would use a tuple:

```
return (x, y)
```

Or, in an OOP language like Java, I would create a custom coordinate class:

```
class Coordinates {
  public int x;
  public int y;

  public Coordinates(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

Then return like this:

```
return new Coordinates(x, y);
```

**On to JavaScript.**

In JavaScript, we have the option of returning a simple object:

```
return {x: x, y: y}
```

or a Java-like approach, with a custom object:

```
return new coordinates(x, y)
```

Are there any reasons to use one above the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doing this is the best (and verbose) option right now.

```
return {x: x, y: y}
```

Or, less verbose but cleaner

```
return {x, y}
```

---

The caller would have to do this to use the values

```
var c = get_coords();
alert(c.x + ' ' + c.y);    // c.x and c.y holds the coordinates
```

If you care to use only single axis you could do -

```
alert(get_coords().x);
```

---

With the ECMAScript 6 you would be able to do destructuring (in caller).

```
var { x, y } = get_coords();
```

Too bad that we'll have to wait quite long to use ECMAScript 6 safely in production (in a cross-browser manner).

More info on destructuring - http://fitzgeraldnick.com/weblog/50/

Answer (score 3):

It depends entirely on what the calling code is expected to do with the returned coordinates. If your current code just needs direct access to the `x` and `y` properties, use the literal:

```
return {x: x, y: y};
```

Or with modern and/or transpiled JavaScript:

```
return { x, y };
```

If you need a more sophisticated return value, just change it:

```
return new Coordinates(x, y);
```

Or this:

```
return BuildCoordinate(x, y);
```

As long as the new return-value has `x` and `y` properties (or getters), your legacy code will still work.

As noted in Sayem's answer, you can also "destructure" return values in ECMAScript 6, or if you're using a web-aware transpiler/builder:

```
let { x, y } = get_coords();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the both approaches are equal, since **both are Objects** with same properties, just  different prototypes.

For the sake of simplicity, you should probably go with the first option. Or even simpler, with the array of the form `[x, y]`.

Comment: Why an array? Using an array for this purpose seems bad because you are introducing an implicit assumption that element 0 is x and element 1 is y.

Comment: Yeah, sure, and in some I am. In mathematics, we have N-dimensonal spaces, in this example 2-D space, first cooridinate is x and second y. In case of 3-D space it might have been [x, y, z]. This way you gain some performace.

Answer (score 0):

**Use the one that matches the meaning of your data.**

My overwhelming habit is to use simple object literals like dictionaries/hashes and to use custom-prototyped-objects in an OOP manner.

Are you returning a simple collection of convenient values which will be immediately disassembled by the calling function? Then use a quick object literal.

Is your return value a *thing* that *does* and *represents* important conceptual stuff in your data model? Then take the time to write a constructor and make it a prototyped instance.

Sure, javascript lets us be flexible (sloppy) and clever (cryptically) by blending these ideas, but I find my code is much clearer if I stick to this rule.